# Is it possible to integrate a forge project directly on bim360?

Tags: autodesk, forge, autodesk-bim360

i know forge as api to make your own site with a connection to bim360 and host it on your own server. But now i want to add a button to bim360 to do something directly on bim360, is this possible with forge? Or is that another api?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something the [Branded Partner Cards](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/guidref/BIM360D/NaN/learn-explore/BIM360D_Insight_About_Partner_Data_and_Analytics_To_Work_with_Partner_Cards_html) are supposed to enable.